# The package "@react-native-community/geolocation" doesn't seem to be linked. React-native version 0.72.5

Tags: react-native, react-native-community

I want to use the react-native-community/geolocation in my project. I followed [this documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/michalchudziak/react-native-geolocation), including the editing of the AndroidManifest.xml etc..

Installing it via

```
npm install @react-native-community/geolocation --save
```

and importing it in the project via

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
```

The error is:

[image]

My package.json (after uninstalling geolocation):

[image: package.json file]

I tried downgrading the geolocation library to 2.0.2; linking the module manually and following the workarounds [described here](https://github.com/michalchudziak/react-native-geolocation/issues/221). Nothing seems to work.

Comment: your package.json is missing the library

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaq I uninstalled the package after it wasn't working. I checked when running npm install if the package.json is updated and that was the case, so this is not the issue

Comment: after installing this package you have to delete the old build. go to andoird folder and Bradley clean then again build the project and test it

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaq I ran ./gradlew clean after installing or changing version of geolocation. Usually, this shouldn't be necessary but as a precaution I did try. No luck though